# I want generate a digital book from Github repository but there's a problem with my command gem or gems from Ruby on Windows 10

Tags: github, windows-10, bundler

I want to generate a digital book from GitHub repository, but there's a problem with my command gem or gems from Ruby on Windows 10

When I want to execute for example as the repository explain to me on my directory

```
bundle install
```

An error occurs related to "undefined method untaint"

```
undefined method untaint String:Method Error
```

It's a bug in older ruby versions, but I have a ruby version 2.4.18, but this repository was
created with version 1.16.5, so my system installed the version of Bundler 1.16.5, it's a problem
because generate the bug
How can I solve it?

I want to generate the digital book in GitHub to use ruby and Asciidoctor.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`core/Object:untaint`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Object:untaint) mentions:

> This method is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

So double-check your `ruby -v` version.
Using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) could help to make sure your project is using the right Ruby version.
Then try `gem install bundler -v '1.16.5'`.